# What law enforcement agency owns the airplane continually circling over south Wichita KS right now 8:45-9:15 AM CDT 3-11-24?

Tags: aircraft-identification

What law enforcement agency owns the airplane continually circling over south Wichita KS right now 8:45-9:15 AM CDT 3-11-24?

Details:  estimated altitude 2500-3000' AGL.  High-wing Cessna, 182 or larger, with struts, fixed tricycle landing gear.  LIDAR or TV or FLIR camera turret on underside, aft of cabin, left of aircraft centerline.  White, except upper 2/3 of vertical fin dark, upper part of fuselage from just aft of cabin to front of nose dark from a few inches below bottom of windows on upwards, wingtip fairings dark.  Dark color is black or dark blue.  Flaps are extended about 10 degrees.

I can't find them on FlightAware or FlightRadar24.

A plane was also doing similar circles for over an hour last night but likely a bit lower, almost certainly the same plane.

Bonus question: what are they doing?  Why so much circling over the city?

Comment: Still circling 9:30, south of Kellogg street (K-54/US-400), likely over or a bit east of I-135

Comment: Circling again now 3/15/25 21:10 CDT, guessing likely same a/c, bright white lights just inboard of wingtip navigation lights

Answer (score 1):

Still circling 9:45 but a bit further north, think I just got the answer, last 2 digits of N# are "HP", maybe "N..........0HP".  Relevant: https://kansashighwaypatrol.gov/find-a-troop/troop-location-map/special-operations/troop-t-aircraft/ -- so likely a Cessna 206.  See https://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/Search/NameResult?nametxt=KANSAS+HIGHWAY+PATROL&sort_option=1.  Matches this paint scheme https://photos.flightaware.com/photos/retriever/99766af79f9b2dd02f16dcc273ad5081b58a086c from https://www.flightaware.com/live/flight/N940HP.
N900HP, N940HP, and N950HP all appear to be possible candidates (all Cessna 206's, and FlightAware shows similar paint schemes on all three), although the KHP website indicates that only two out these three have the FLIR camera, which is presumably the object visible aft of the cabin in the photo.  Image below is from link above.

[image]

Comment: this seems fairly accurate for finding it. if they aren't transmitting ADSB, sometimes you'll get lucky with TIS-B to see the circling (it'll show up on [globe.adsbexchange.com](https://globe.adsbexchange.com)). The other good place is liveatc; they are probably communicating with an "idaho" call sign, eg "Idaho 11". They're allowed to turn ADSB off when operational.

Comment: @300D7309EF17 -- re "They're allowed to turn ADSB off when operational. " -- thanks for mentioning that

Comment: Different paint scheme, but the Civil Air Patrol uses similarly equipped Cessnas, for Predator/Reaper UAV training. https://www.airandspaceforces.com/article/cap-joins-the-total-force/